# Disable ListView selection on Tap in a Metro Style App

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am trying to allow swipe as the only method to select an item in my ListView (a la tiles).  Is there any way to stop a ListView from changing selection when you tap on an item?

I've tried putting IsTapEnabled on everything I can, the ListView and also a copy of the ItemContainerStyle, where I did so on all the visual elements to no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you can do so by setting IsItemClickEnabled to true.  As per Mark Rideout: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/2572f184-b163-4732-9a9d-8d5c404e40b5